# Paypal sandbox always responds with "User authentication failed" (code: 1)

Tags: authentication, paypal

URL: https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com
Until 12 April 2017 I had no problem but as of 13 April I failed to create a secure token.
There were no changes to the code nor to the account settings (no change in password, no "allowed IP addresses, ..."). 
The same code using paypal production accounts still works.
Apart from the TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 upgrade I don't know about any changes on the PayPal server side.
Anyone having similar problems?

Comment: This site is requiring a client certificate in order to access it.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I decided to contact PayPal technical support and I eventually (after 5 weeks) got this reply:

"There was a batch a few months ago that disabled Test accounts that hadn't been in use for a while.
They can be re-enabled only from our side... 
Apologies for the inconveniences."

They kindly re-enabled our accounts and all was fine again.

Comment: A valuable lesson: sometimes it's just PayPal's fault. Sorry to hear about all that wasted time.